# Instance member 'param' cannot be used on type 'LoginViewController' [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode

Looking at this question, I tried to fix the error but it failed

**[Instance member cannot be use on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472475/instance-member-cannot-be-use-on-type)**

I tried to pass the param value to another file, but an error appeared. What should I do? I tried several methods but failed because I didn't understand it.

**LoginViewController**

```
var param: String?
@IBOutlet var inputId: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputPass: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NetworkHandler.LoginBoard({ LoginList in
        self.LoginList = LoginList
        }, param: param ?? "")
}
@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
   param = "userId=\(inputId.text ?? "")&userPw=\(inputPass.text ?? "")"
   print("This is Param = ",param!)
}
```

**NetworkHandler**

```
class func LoginBoard(_ completeHandler: @escaping (Login) -> Void, param: String) {
     let loginboard: String = MAIN_URL + "/member/login"
     guard let url = URL(string: loginboard) else 
       print("Error: cannot create URL")
         return
     }
       LoginViewController.param = param // ERROR [Instance member 'param' cannot be used on type 'LoginViewController']
}
```

The rest of the code is related to urlsession connection, so I don't think I need it, Only some codesattach
It's not perfect yet, so I'm not sure which one is the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's basically saying, `you don't have an actual object` on which you can set the values.

You need to understand what's a `class` and what's an `instance`. I'd suggest to revisit and clear your basics. That'd fix your understanding.

Okay the answer to this particular question, as `param` is an `instance property` and not a `class property`(class properties are static), you cannot set the value of param unless you `create an instance`.

Create an instance of `LoginViewController` like

```
let controller = LoginViewController()
controller.param = param
```

Comment: Thank you, but the **param** value is not delivered to the ```networkHandler``` file although we have been doing it since yesterday.